# No entiendo este error de ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax, phpmyadmin

Tengo el siguiente error con ajax. Tengo un producto.php donde cree una funcion que se llama iniciar_compra(), dentro de esta funcion tengo el siguiente condigo de ajax.

```
$.ajax({
                url:'servicios/compra/validar_inicio_compra.php',
                type:'POST',
                data:{
                    codpro:p,
                    cantprod:document.getElementById("quantity-input").value
                    
                    
                },
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data.state) {
                        alert(data.detail);
                    }else{
                        alert(data.detail);
                        if (data.open_login) {
                            open_login();
                        }
                    }
                },
                error:function(err){
                    console.error(err);
                }
            });
        }
```

Lo que hace este codigo es pasarle a una clase que se llama validar_inicio_compra.php un "p" que es el codigo del producto que mas arriba cree un script donde lo capta de la siguiente manera:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var p='<?php echo $_GET["p"]; ?>';
    </script>
```

Y tambien le pasa el valor de un input que es cantprod.
Mi clase validar_inicio_compra.php es la siguiente:

```
<?php
session_start();
$response=new stdClass();

if (!isset($_SESSION['codusu'])) {
    $response->state=false;
    $response->detail="No esta logeado";
    $response->open_login=true;
}else{
    include_once('../_conexion.php');
    $codusu=$_SESSION['codusu'];
    $codpro=$_POST['codpro'];
    $cantpro=$_POST['cantprod'];
    $sql="INSERT INTO pedido
    (codusu,codpro,fecped,estado,dirusuped,telusuped,cantpro)
    VALUES
    ($codusu,$codpro,now(),1,'','',$cantpro)";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if ($result) {
        $response->state=true;
        $response->detail="Producto agregado";
        header('Location: ../');
    }else{
        $response->state=false;
        $response->detail="No se pudo agregar producto. Intente más tarde";
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

Esto funciona correctamente excepto en la parte `$response->detail="Producto agregado";`, se supone que deberia saltarme una ventana de alerta que diga Producto agregado pero no me salta, lo que me salta es una ventana que dice undefined
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando me voy a la consola a mirar que pasa me aparece esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
No tengo ni idea porque me aparece esto.

Comment: nos serviría la petición http que hace el navegador, podrías colocar le detalle? un ejemplo [aqui](https://i.imgur.com/SKk4ea0.png)

Comment: ¿¿porque pones un `header('Location: ../');`??  Quitalo a ver si va a ser eso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conviene que comprendas que Ajax es como una pasarela entre el cliente (Javascript/HTML) y el servidor (PHP). El archivo que sirve para enviar los datos es el que pones en el parámetro `url` de la petición Ajax. Gracias a ese archivo, tú no necesitas recargar la página para mandar los datos, ni necesitas hacer cosas como esta mostrar en el cliente lo que ocurre en el servidor:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var p='<?php echo $_GET["p"]; ?>';
</script>
```

Tampoco necesitas redirigir a ninguna parte, ni desde el cliente, ni desde el servidor, como haces aquí:

```
header('Location: ../');
```

Nada de esto es necesario cuando usas Ajax, de hecho, Ajax se creó justamente para evitar este tipo de cosas y permitir una comunicación limpia entre cliente / servidor, donde todo se pasa por medio del archivo que pones en el parámetro `url`, este mismo archivo devuelve una respuesta cuando sea necesario y dicha respuesta es recibida dentro del bloque `success`. No hay más historia... si entiendes esto, no tendrás ningún problema escribiendo tu código.

Otra cosa importante es que en Ajax basado en jQuery, los datos se pasan con el parámetro `data`, como de hecho haces, PERO, cuando buscas esos datos en el servidor **debes buscar los datos por la clave que hay a la izquierda de cada valor**.

Si observas tu `data` en el código Javascript:

```
data:{
       codpro:p,
       cantprod:document.getElementById("quantity-input").value
      },
```

Estarías pasando **dos datos**, y esos datos estarían bajo las claves `codpro` y `cantpro`. Digo esto porque en tu código se ve un intento como este:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var p='<?php echo $_GET["p"]; ?>';
</script>
```

¿Qué sentido tiene eso? ¿Estás buscando un dato bajo la clave `p`? Además, como dije más arriba, ese `script` es contrario al propósito de Ajax. Quita por tanto esa parte en tu código.

En `validar_inicio_compra.php` el código sí parece correcto, pues buscas los datos bajo las claves correctas:

```
$codpro=$_POST['codpro'];
$cantpro=$_POST['cantprod'];
```

El gran problema ahí sería este:

```
header('Location: ../');
```

Haciendo esto, tú rediriges a quién sabe donde, rompiendo totalmente el flujo. Como dije al principio, la respuesta de tu petición Ajax debe regresar al cliente, y la vas a recibir en el `success`. Si tú ahora mandas a otro sitio, el cliente no recibirá los datos. Por tanto borra esa línea.

También, para evitar eventuales problemas con acentos, indica el charset en la cabecera:

```
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
echo json_encode($response);
```

Finalmente, tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *inyección SQL*. Considera usar consultas preparadas para neutralizar ese riesgo.

Comment: Esta linea de codigo la hago fuera de la funcion iniciar_compra()                                                                                         `<script type="text/javascript">
    var p='<?php echo $_GET["p"]; ?>';
</script>`

Comment: Si borro este script se me daña todo ya que lo que hace el script es guardar en una variable p el id del producto. porque el id del producto lo paso por la URL un ejemplo aca http://localhost/Ecommerce/producto.php?p=3 despues de la p hay un igual 3, el 3 seria el codigo del producto y en mi script se guardaria un 3 en la variable p, en el ajax lo que hago es enviarle este 3 para que haga el insert en la base de datos.

Comment: No se si sea la manera mas idonea de enviar este id_producto, pero es la forma como lo estoy haciendo, me podrias explicar una mejor forma para no romper el proposito con el que se hizo ajax?

Comment: @JuanJose si tú quieres mandar ese dato, lo puedes hacer desde `data`, como expliqué en la respuesta. ¿Acaso no es ese valor el que mandas aquí: `codpro:p,`? ¿Esa `p` no representa tu valor (3)? Lo que me extraña es que recojas ese valor con `$_GET`, cuando `$_GET` está del lado del servidor, eso no tiene sentido.